# Are there any Firebase legacy docs anywhere?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm still using firebase 2.x and just noticed the firebase.com website now redirects to firebase.google.com.  Are the old docs available anywhere?  Even if I could just download them for future reference.

Comment: This is still active [Firebase iOS](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference, Current and Official Documentation link is:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/

I just removed the `.google` like it was before. The legacy docs are still there.

https://firebase.com/docs/

Comment: It  has been around 6 years since Google acquired Firebase. Removing the legacy (outdated) docs is bound to happen.

Comment: I’m not necessarily surprised, it’s just disappointing if you have to support an old version. Thank goodness for Typescript, otherwise I might be in a really bad state.

Answer (score 2):

The old docs are not officially around anymore (2020).

However, you can access them using [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://firebase.com/docs/).